# How can I set the layout and the filters for an object exploration through the URL?

Tags: palantir-foundry, palantir-foundry-api

Is there a way to open an object exploration of a certain object type and simultaneously set the layout of the exploration and add filters? I was looking at [this page](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/object-explorer/generate-urls/) in the docs that explains how to define the filter values but I am not sure how to set a layout at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a layout RID after the filters, to the end of your URL like this:

```
https://<stack>.palantircloud.com/workspace/hubble/external/search/v2/{your filters}?layoutRid={layout_RID}
```